# formatting in razor nested webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm nesting a webgrid inside another webgrid as shown in [Razor Nested WebGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732736/razor-nested-webgrid)

But when I try to format the columns inside the nested webgrid it's throwing an error stating that the column in the mastergrid has invalid arguments.

Has anyone faced this problem before?

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Arnab

Comment: Can you post some sample code what you have tried and also the message of the exception?

Comment: code is the same as of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732736/razor-nested-webgrid and the error seems to be coming because of the format option in mastergrid is somehow clashing with format in nested grid

Comment: If my answer is not working for you please update your post with your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is that you tried to use the same parameter name `item` in the inner `format` parameter. You cannot use the same parameter name in nested lambda expressions. You can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) more about lambda expressions.
So you need to use a different parameter name (e.g. `subItem`) for the inner format:

```
...
    @topGrid.GetHtml(columns:
        topGrid.Columns(
            topGrid.Column("Index"),
            topGrid.Column("SubItems", format: (item) =>
            {
                WebGrid subGrid = subGrid = new WebGrid(item.SubItems);
                return subGrid.GetHtml(
                        columns: subGrid.Columns(
                        subGrid.Column("A", format: (subItem) => string.Format("Formatted: {0}", subItem.A)),
                            subGrid.Column("B")
                        )
                    );
            })
        )
    )
...
```