# WebMatrix Nested WebGrid VB code

Tags: vb.net, razor, webmatrix, webgrid, nested

I have looked at the code in both the following posts:

1. [formatting in razor nested webgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947072/formatting-in-razor-nested-webgrid), replied to by nemesv in October 2011 and
2. [Razor Nested WebGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732736/razor-nested-webgrid), replied to by Chad Moran in April 2011.

They both seem to be close to my problem but the code is C# based, I believe, and I am having difficulty converting it to VB.  I am also not sure they are exactly where I am at.  I am particularly bemused by the following line, because of the two equals signs and double reference to subGrid.

```
WebGrid subGrid = subGrid = new WebGrid(item.SubItems)
```

I am also not sure whether topGrid and subGrid are just generic names, used for the purpose of illustration, or whether they are key words.

As a very relevant aside I will mention that this point in my web page project has held me up for five years now (I am not exaggerating - I just stopped working on the project for two years because of it).  I have tried using ASP in VWD and now Grid View in WebMatrix and I hope I will not fail again.

**Database record**

Fields: Publisher_Name, Publisher_City, Series_Published, No_of_Series

Record Example: Price Stern Sloan, Baltimore, JKLMNO, 6

**My two planned grid names**

Publishers_Grid (top)
Series_Grid (sub)

**What I am trying to do**

1. For each of the characters in the string JKLMNO, access a second table, where each letter is the primary key for a record in that table.
2. Retrieve the value of the field, Back_Cover_Image, in that second table, which will be the file name or, at least, the unique part of the file name, for the image to be displayed.
3. If I go with the partial unique bit of file name approach, build the full file names for the images.  And then -
4. Display as a second web grid row, the images thus pointed at, in the record example, that would be 6 images.

Thus I would end up, for the example record, something like the following (I have used XX to stand for an image): -

```
Price Stern Sloan    Baltimore    XX  XX  XX  XX  XX  XX
```

I certainly I hope I am not wasting the valuable time of experts who I greatly admire.  I'm just trying to achieve something that seems quite simple to me, having originally been a PL/1 programmer, 30 years ago, and a great user of nested arrays within that language, but I just can't work out the syntax in VB, Razor and WebMatrix.

I look forward to some constructive answers, and please do use VB.

**My WebMatrix page so far**

```
@Code

    Layout = "~/Shared/Layouts/_Layout.vbhtml"

     Dim HWB_Database As Database = Database.Open("How_and_Why_Wonder_Books")
     Dim HWB_Publishers_All_sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM Publishers ORDER BY Publisher_Code"
     Dim Publishers_Data = HWB_Database.Query(HWB_Publishers_All_sqlCommand)
     Dim Publishers_Grid = New WebGrid(Publishers_Data)

End Code

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>How and Why Wonder Books - Publishers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="margin-left: 100px">
         <p  style="Width: 1020px; border-width: 1px" class="InstructionsHeader">
          Click on a publisher to see the list of titles produced under that imprint, click on a thumbnail to see details of that series type.
         </p>
        </div>
     <br>               
     <br>               
        <div id="Publishers_Grid_Display">
         @Publishers_Grid.GetHtml(columns:= Publishers_Grid.Columns(
                                                                     Publishers_Grid.Column("Publisher_Name"),
                                                         Publishers_Grid.Column("Place_of_Publication"),
                                                      Publishers_Grid.Column("Series_Published")
                                                      )
        )
        </div>
```

Thank you for your promptings and encouragement.

Comment: Please show the code you have so far. Also please link to the questions you are talking about. Saying `replied to by nemesv in October 2011` and `replied to by Chad Moran in April 2011` means nothing when you have millions of questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Please tell me how to create such links - I wanted to actually post this as a follow up to one of those previous questions, like I would on a Microsoft forum, but I couldn't find a way of doing so.

Comment: There's no such notion as follow-up question on StackOverflow. As far as creating a link is concerned, you should use the hyperlink icon when typing text. Also read the [`Markdown tips`](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - orange question mark button to better understand the different formats that you could use when typing text. More specifically there's a paragraph called [`Links`](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links).

Comment: I just added the code, as requested.  I tried to follow the instructions re putting the links in, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Please feel free to edit them so they work properly, and so I learn what mistake I have made.  I see the text, of what I have tried to do, when I edit the post.

Comment: What isn't working?  I hope you don't take this the wrong way, but you never actually said what the problem is.

Comment: Dear Clay

Publishers_Grid.Column("Series_Published") produces the string out of Series_Published.

What I am wanting is an inner grid of JPEGS as pointed at by each letter of the string Series_Published, so as per the example data I don't want the string JKLMNO( which is what I've got now), but rather a row of JPEGs as pointed at by J, K, L, M, N, O, each letter being the primary key to a record in the Series table where there is a field Image_Name.  This is what I set out under the heading "What I am trying to do", in the original post.  Thank you for taking an interest.